# Using IMPORTXML to extract a SPAN value deeply imbedded within multiple DIVs

Tags: html, import, google-sheets

Using IMPORTXML, how can I pull out the values "237" (span class="flirblue") and "99" (span class="cents") from the following HTML?

```
<div class="row visible-xs text-center mobile-price-panel" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding: 7px 0px;">
    <div class="col-xs-6"><span class="pricing">€</span><span class="flirblue">237,</span><span class="cents">99</span> </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><a class="btn btn-primary main-buy-button btn-group-justified page-scroll" href="#models">VORBESTELLEN</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have only just started fiddling with IMPORTXML, and have gotten a number of them to work perfectly on several different websites, but I just cannot find a way to get the 237 and the 99 off one particular site, of which the above is an example of the HTML.

My last attempt on the above was:

```
=ImportXML("URL","//div[@class='row visible-xs text-center mobile-price-panel']//div[@class='col-xs-12']//div[@class='col-xs-6']//span[@class='flirblue']")
```

But it does not work, and no matter how I fiddle.

Please help.

Kind regards

Padster

Answer (score 0):

Name directly the class you want.

Example for `Flirblue`:

```
=ImportXML("URL","//div[@class='flirblue']")
```

Some minor tweaking required, but should work.